# SK.action runs through action several times

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a SKAction that runs an action if an area on the screen is touched. However I cannot get the SKanimate to only run through the SKarray once (both actions that is), it seems to run around 4 times. The count parameter doesn't seem to make any difference either. Any help on how to get it to run through the frames in the array just once then stop would be appreciated!

```
//Touch location check
for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)



    if myButton.contains(location) {
        //run shoot animation.

        MainGuy.run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: TextureArrayShoot, timePerFrame: 0.10), count: 1),withKey: "outlaw")

        print ("touched")
        let witchaction = SKAction.animate(with: TextureArrayWitch, timePerFrame: 0.20)
        witch.run(witchaction)


        missedLabel1.text = "Good Shot!"
    }
}
```

Comment: would need to see how you are making your array

Comment: No problem:

  for i in 0...3{
            let NameShoot = "shoot\(i)"
            TextureArrayShoot.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: NameShoot))
            }
            
        //prep texture array for WITCH
        for i in 1...6{
            let NameWitch = "w\(i)"
            TextureArrayWitch.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: NameWitch))

Comment: sorry I don't know how to make the comments code! ^

Comment: Just edit your question and add it to the question

Comment: @BarronAce why are you using `SKAction.repeat(:_:_)` if you only want to run the action once?

Comment: @JonathanHanna I have just noticed that, but the second one (witch action) is just a normal SKaction.animate and seems to have the same problem?

Comment: @BarronAce double check your array and make sure it doesn't have duplicate values. From the limited code you provided, that's all that can be reasonably speculated.

Comment: Is this in `touchesBegan` or `touchesMoved`? Or both?

Comment: sorry - just touches began

Comment: UPDATE: printing the size of the arrays seems to show that each image is being added to the array 5 times. Why it is doing that I still am not aware of? @JonathanHanna

Comment: @BarronAce I obviously can't tell you unless you **provide code** for the creation / initialization and any modifications to values of your arrays.

Comment: Apologies - solved it. There were 3 arrays for sprites in a row, and the first one wasn't closed properly and encapsulating the other two, meaning the 'I' in for I in...was being used 3 times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies - solved it. There were 3 arrays for sprites in a row, and the first one wasn't closed properly and encapsulating the other two, meaning the 'I' in for I in...was being used 3 times!